# "Filename could not be loaded" when pulling repo with 2 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2019

I have a project that I successfully pushed to GitHub and made several commits to. Once I added a 2nd project to the solution, I ran into an issue when pulling the repo down.

I do not think the second project has been added to the github repository properly and when I try to download the repo I am seeing "Filename could not be loaded", referring to the 2nd project that was added.

Could someone provide some direction for me on how to solve this?

The repository:
[image: VitekSky Repository]
EDIT:

Screenshot of the error

[image: Project can't be opened error]

EDIT: Link to our github repository: https://github.com/tux-superman/VitekSky

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your Visual Studio project with the error displayed? Seeing the icons that VS displays might help resolve this issue. Can you verify that the `.sln` file for your solution made it into GitHub & was updated appropriately after the new `.csproj` was created?

Comment: I'm not sure if you use the GitHub GUI or console. If you use the GUI can you try out the console? Command: git clone (repo).

Comment: Hehe i cant sry need something called reputation :D

Comment: @Christine images up with Error ---- -EDIT : the project file or web cannot be found

Comment: What happens when you right click `Vitek API (unloaded)` and click `Reload project`?

Comment: "The project could not be completed" -  i thing its maybe not even up on github repo maybe?

Comment: @Christine There is a link to our github repository

Comment: So your `.sln` file references two projects, but I don't think the 2nd project is actually in GitHub. Your last commit where you are trying to add in `VitekAPI` is not really committing anything other than the addition of the project to your solution. Do you own the codebase for `VitekAPI` and does it exist locally? Or are you trying to install it from somewhere and add it? The code is not in your repo at all which is why I am asking.

Comment: @Christine yes we own the codebase for VitekAPI. We have made it ourselves. It exists locally but but we can't commit in visual studio 2019 for some reason. Right now we have a solution called VitekSky and in that solution there is a project called VitekSky which is out MVC and a 2nd project called VitekAPI which is our webAPI. We are not able to commit and push or sync it.

Answer (score 1):

Your [`VitekSky.sln`#L8](https://github.com/tux-superman/VitekSky/blob/2ebce1348ea4fb8cf8a2875abaac1cda66f3d828/VitekSky.sln#L8) includes:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "VitekAPI", "..\VitekAPI\VitekAPI.csproj", "{98C68D33-AAAD-40B6-86F3-C4D1DEC76032}"
```

EndProject

It will look for a `..\VitekAPI\VitekAPI.csproj` which would be *outside* your current Git repository.

If both projects are versioned, they should be versionned in the same GitHub repository (which currently does not include any VitekAPI folder)